# NHibernate prefixing table name with a schema

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

How can you prefix table names in the following format

```
[schema][.][tableName]
```

If i do the following

```
public class PrescriptionOverride : AutoMappingOverride<Prescription>
{
    mapping.Table("schema.TableName);
}
```

doesn't work, if the schema doesn't actually exists in the DB. It will actually ignore the table.

> 'TableName'

from being mapped

So how can you create an SQL Schema with NHibernate so that you can use that schema to attach a table to it.

SQL equivalent :

```
  create schema [mySchema]
  go
  create table [mySchema].[MyTable](id int)
```

Comment: have you tried `Schema("schemaName");`?

Comment: no, I'm kind of new to NHibernate so I didn't knew anything about an option like this. I will look into it. Thanks

Comment: Her are [fluent hints](https://github.com/FluentNHibernate/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Using-multiple-or-different-schemas) and [mapping by code](http://notherdev.blogspot.com/2012/02/mapping-by-code-entity-level-mappings.html) ones

Comment: @RadimKöhler, can you help me with using the schema option ? I've tried using **mapping.Schema("test");** and then **mapping.Table("myTable")** but couldn't make it to work. Any idea what am i doing wrong ? I assume that the schema will be created automatically if it doesn't exists. I'm using **IAutoMappingOverride<T>** and not **ClassMap<T>**

Comment: As David in his answer pointed out.. we would need a bit more -some special SQL triggers.And that together with `Schema()` setting .. should work

Comment: The word you're looking for is "prefix". When you "suffix", you put it at the end. :)

Comment: You are right, honest mistake

Answer (score 2):

I could create the schema with NHibernate, the problem is that NHibernate first creates the tables and then the auxiliary objects, in this case the schemas. And since the tables use the schemas, and they are not created, configuration will crush.

This is the configuration

```
public SessionFactory InitializeSessionFactory(string connectionString)
{
      FluentConfiguration fluentConfiguration = Fluently.Configure();


      fluentConfiguration
          .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2012.Dialect<MsSql2012Dialect>().ConnectionString(connectionString));

      fluentConfiguration
           .ExposeConfiguration((config) =>
            {
                config.AddAuxiliaryDatabaseObject(new CreateSchema("mySchema"));
                new SchemaExport(config).Create(false, true);
            });


      fluentConfiguration
            .Mappings(....);


       ISessionFactory sessionFactory = fluentConfiguration
             .BuildConfiguration()
             .BuildSessionFactory();

       return sessionFactory ;
}
```

This is the Auxiliary Object

```
public class CreateSchema : AbstractAuxiliaryDatabaseObject
{
    string _schemaName;

    public CreateSchema(string name) { _schemaName = name; }

    public override string SqlCreateString(Dialect dialect, IMapping p, string defaultCatalog, string defaultSchema)
    {
        return $"CREATE SCHEMA {_schemaName }";
    }

    public override string SqlDropString(Dialect dialect, string defaultCatalog, string defaultSchema)
    {
        return $"DROP SCHEMA {_schemaName }";
    }
}
```

This is how I'm using it.

```
public class EntityOverride : IAutoMappingOverride<Entity>
{
      void IAutoMappingOverride<Entity>.Override(AutoMapping<Entity> mapping)
      {
           mapping.Schema("mySchema");
      }
}
```

I've chose another approach. I create the schemas via SqlCommand at application initialization and then I just use the schemas.

This is how I'm doing it

```
 public sealed class SqlSchemaCreator
    {
        private static Lazy<SqlSchemaCreator> _instance = new Lazy<SqlSchemaCreator>(() => new SqlSchemaCreator());

        public static SqlSchemaCreator Instance { get => _instance.Value; }

        private SqlSchemaCreator()
        {

        }

        public void CreateSchemas(string connectionString, List<string> schemas)
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();

                using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    foreach (string schema in schemas)
                    {
                        string query = $"IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.schemas WHERE name = '{schema.ToLower()}') BEGIN EXEC ('CREATE SCHEMA {schema.ToLower()}') END";

                        command.CommandText = query;

                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And then just use.

```
public class EntityOverride : IAutoMappingOverride<Entity>
{
     void IAutoMappingOverride<Entity>.Override(AutoMapping<Entity> mapping)
     {
          mapping.Schema("mySchema");
     }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to use [auxiliary database objects](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/mapping.html#mapping-database-object) to create the schema if it doesn't already exist. However, these take effect when you use NH to create the database schema.

```
public class CreateSchema : AbstractAuxiliaryDatabaseObject
{
    public override string SqlCreateString(Dialect dialect, IMapping p, string defaultCatalog, string defaultSchema)
    {
        return "CREATE SCHEMA [mySchema]";
    }

    public override string SqlDropString(Dialect dialect, string defaultCatalog, string defaultSchema)
    {
        return "DROP SCHEMA [mySchema]";
    }
}
```

Then you need to add it to your config:

```
config.AddAuxiliaryDatabaseObject(new CreateSchema());
```

It will take effect when you do:

```
new SchemaExport(config).Create(true, true);
```

or:

```
new SchemaExport(config).Drop(true, true);
```